# Changing the video src on click

Tags: jquery

Trying to swap out youtube videos based on which ever thumbnail the user clicks. So, you see the video, and 2 thumbnails below. If you click one of the thumbs, the video changes. I've got it to change, the video id doesn't change. It says undefined. I'm trying to figure out how to use the array to swap video ids. Thank you guys in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="video_container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vOnCRWUsSGA?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
</div>

<div class="thumbs">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.thumbs img').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var vID = new Array(
        'hZ8Xj_I3aNU',
        'luyOn5DdUZs'
    );

    var URL = $(this).attr('src');
    var videoPlayer = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '/?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=0&autohide=1&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    $('##video_container').html(videoPlayer);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: `##video_container` a typo? Should be `#video_container` Also three slashes in a row is not a good idea too

Comment: Why do you need to change the video ***id*** ?

Comment: You are not doing anything with your `vID` variable. Instead, it seems, you are inserting the `src` of the image into the youtube address, which makes no sense at all IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure what your trying to do but would having the video ID be the ID attribute of the images work for you?

```
<div id="video_container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vOnCRWUsSGA?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen >      </iframe>
</div>

<div class="thumbs">
    <img id="hZ8Xj_I3aNU" src="//placehold.it/100">
    <img id="luyOn5DdUZs" src="//placehold.it/100">
</div>

$('.thumbs img').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

            var URL = $(this).attr('id');
            var videoPlayer = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '/?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=0&autohide=1&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';



            $('#video_container').html(videoPlayer);
            return false;
        });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mz1brzfp/1/